# assigning value to "default selection parameter" in select_tag - ruby/rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

following is the code of my select tag

```
<%= select_tag "assignee#{cnt}", options_from_collection_for_select(@arr,tmp="id","name" ,     default_selection),  html_options = { :onblur => "myblur(this);", :onChange=> "submit_selected(this);",     :style=> "visibility:visible;" } %>
```

the html generated for above line is like:

```
<select id="assignee1" name="assignee1" onChange="submit_selected(this);" onblur="myblur(this);" style="visibility:visible;">

<option value="12">Name1</option>
<option value="48">Name2</option>
<option value="15">Name3</option>
<option value="35">Name4</option>

</select>
```

now in the default_selection paramter, i want to use the option value corresponding to option text. i have the option text.

say, i have "Name1" and i want to use its option value i.e 12 in default_selection parameter

any comments?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> any comments?

Yes ;) Indeed your question is not related to this portion of code. You just have to search in your object @arr.

My bet :

```
default_opt = @arr.select {|o| o.name == 'Name1'}
default_selection = default_opt.id if default_opt
```

Then generate your `<select>` as you have already done.